# adding sequence number to a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have added a new column seq_col containing unique sequence using

```
  val df2 = dfFromRDD1.withColumn("monotonically_increasing_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  val window = Window.orderBy(col("monotonically_increasing_id"))
  val df3_consecutiveval = df2.withColumn("seq_col",row_number().over(window)).drop(col("monotonically_increasing_id").show()

dataframe:

col1  col2 seq_col
a    aa   1
b    ff   2
c    rr   3
d    yy   4
e    tt   5
```

Now I want to add values to that new column in dataframe which will have data based on start and increment values specified like below example

Ex:
Start = 100
increment = 3

```
dataframe:

col1  col2 seq_col
a    aa   100
b    ff   103
c    rr   106
d    yy   109
e    tt   112
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `udf` that is responsible to calculate the id with the given logic, for instance in this case:

```scala
val step = 3 // increment 3 by 3
val startOffset = 100 // you want it to start with 100
val calculateId = udf((rowNum: Int) => startOffset + (rowNum * step))

df.withColumn("seq_col", calculateId(row_number().over(window))
```

This worked for me using some random dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for help... i see in your case it generating the sequence from 103 and not from 100...i need it to start from offset

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is technically correct, but you should avoid using udfs whenever possible for performance reasons. This case is so simple that basic arithmetic will do the trick:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("a", "aa"), ("b", "ff"), ("c", "rr"), ("d", "yy"), ("e", "tt")).toDF("col1", "col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string]

scala> val start = 100
start: Int = 100

scala> val increment = 3
increment: Int = 3

scala> df.withColumn("seq_col", monotonically_increasing_id() * increment + start).show
+----+----+-------+
|col1|col2|seq_col|
+----+----+-------+
|   a|  aa|    100|
|   b|  ff|    103|
|   c|  rr|    106|
|   d|  yy|    109|
|   e|  tt|    112|
+----+----+-------+


scala>
```

Comment: i used the same code but how monotonically_increasing_id() * something  generating continuous numbers for me using your code generated below:
  val start = 100
  val increment = 3
  df2.withColumn("seq_col", monotonically_increasing_id() * increment + start).show
+-----------+
|    seq_col|
+-----------+
|        100|
|        103|
|25769803876|
|25769803879|
|25769803882|
+-----------+

Comment: Dataframes and Datasets have no inherent ordering. When you call `show()` you aren't getting the first twenty rows, you're getting whatever 20 rows Spark can grab the quickest. You should add an `orderBy()` clause before adding `seq_col`.

Comment: Ok.. Actually I was using the same dataset but i found its because i was parallelizing the data like val data = Seq(("a", "aa"), ("b", "ff"), ("c", "rr"), ("d", "yy"), ("e", "tt"))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val dfFromRDD1 = rdd.toDF("col1","col2")
Can you help me to understand when i am using paralelize why am i getting random value for monotonically_increasing_id(). because after removing it I am indeed getting your output